# AttributeError for sessionmaker

Tags: sqlalchemy, attributeerror

im new in python and still learning
this is my code :

```py
# import libraries
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import psycopg2

# creating the engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password123@localhost:5432/alchemy', echo=False)

# creating the session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session

# creating the table
Base = declarative_base()


# creating the class that inherit the base

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "student"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    age = Column(Integer)
    grade = Column(String)


# migrating table to database

## Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# create instance os table class

student1 = Student(name="mike", age=32, grade="second")
student2 = Student(name="jenn", age=31, grade="first")
student3 = Student(name="joe", age=23, grade="third")
student4 = Student(name="jack", age=26, grade="forth")
student5 = Student(name="rose", age=28, grade="fifth")

# add data to the session we created before
"""the 'Base.metadata.create_all(engine)' line will transfer to comment after this part because we dont need migrate 
in this execution"""

session.add_all()
session.commit()
```

after running the code i constantly getting this error

line 45, in 
session.add_all()
AttributeError: 'sessionmaker' object has no attribute 'add_all'

same error comes for method 'commit()' too

im using pycharm all module and IDE is updated , a light bulb appear near the line and ask for adding this method to the library
sqlalcheamy (2.0.17)
python 3.11

i have checked some other stackoverflow questions, they usually used flask which i dont know what is it , im stil trying to learn sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
session = Session()
```

You're missing the parentheses. A call to `sessionmaker` returns a `Session`
object.

Also, use a context manager:

```py
with Session() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
    session.commit()
```

For more information, check the documentation:
[Using a sessionmaker](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#using-a-sessionmaker)

Answer (score 0):

Context manager will work only for sqlalchemy higher then 1.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).